Issue installing "arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc" and "arm-linux-gnueabihf" , unable to locate package
first time posting, and really need some help.
So im currently on WSL trying to install some cross compilers with the following command,based off some old documentation that i found:

sudo apt install arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc arm-linux-gnueabihf
gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu

But somehow it keeps giving me the error
"E: Unable to locate package arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
E: Unable to locate package arm-linux-gnueabihf"
But gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf and gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu seems to install fine.
I try to look around but cant seem to find out about these 2 package.
Could someone help to shed some light on this?
But i cant seem to get the "arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc" and "arm-linux-gnueabihf" to install.
Thanks for the help in advance guys.
Edit:
Im on Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy

Hey sorry Im quite new to this. First time going into linux so im quite green.
Basically im on Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy

The cross compilers that you are unable to locate yet can be located in Ubuntu 22.04 by running the following apt command to search for the relevant packages:
apt search gnueabihf

On Ubuntu 22.04 this command returns matches for gcc-11-arm-linux-gnueabihf, gcc-12-arm-linux-gnueabihf, binutils-arm-linux-gnueabihf-dbg and many other packages depending on what programming language source code files you are trying to cross compile. Packages exist for GNU C, GNU C++, GNU Objective-C, GNU Go, GNU Rust, GNU D, GNU Ada and GNU Fortran compilers.

Thanks bro! appreicate the help!
I got another question, Im trying to figure out how to compile a coremark benchmarker using the arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc or  aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc (I still dont quite get it atm, but learning). Is there a place or good way i could find out how to use the cross compilers commands?

Refer to the CoreMark documentation for specific instructions and guidelines. Consult the documentation of arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc and aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc for detailed usage information. Search for tutorials and discussions related to cross-compiling CoreMark on specific target platforms. Download the CoreMark source code from the official EEMBC website or a trusted repository.
